# Server.Transfer does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

After lots of research still I do not have an answer.

I use WebForm app VS 2013.

My code is fairly simple:

```
Server.Transfer("~/Success.aspx",true);
```

After this, load event of `Success.aspx` is executed but in the browser I only see original Main form.

I created any empty Web Form with only a Button on it but after running the following code

```
  Server.Transfer("~/WebForm2.aspx",true);
```

still I see MainForm.aspx,(Page_load event handler of WebForm2 runs)

==========================

Update per IrishGrifgin's comments.

I indeed have aJax in my code. I do have UpdatePanels which use Ajax.If this is the problem for server.Transfer how can we resolve this?

Comment: Are you calling this on an AJAX-enabled page?

Comment: I dont think so. How can I check this?

Comment: Dont try to find solution, better use other way of design your page. The Server.Transfer is great but if you can not understand whats really do, then avoid it. And in most cases can not work with complicate pages, can not do some of the post backs... simple, find other way - Server.Transfer works - but what is did is not what you expect...

Comment: Can you create a empty project and share it though github maybe.

Comment: Try `Server.TransferRequest` or `HttpServerUtility.TransferRequest`.

Comment: @doctor  same issue with Server.TransferRequest  , I will try HttpServerUtility.TransferRequest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. Thank you all for your help(+1 for everyone who gave me an idea).

So here was my code:

cs:  `Server.Transfer("~/Success.aspx",false);`

HTML:

```
<div id="submit">                   
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />                   

</div>
```

As mentioned Submit button was inside an Update panel.
In this case we need to use the following code :

```
 <Triggers>
       <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" />
  </Triggers>
```

This code basically makes the execution of the submit button Synchronous(overrides the Update-panel Behavior).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you understand what `Server.Transfer()` does.

It temporarily redirects the code to run the code in the second page.. but it returns control back to the original page once complete.  It's entirely possible that the browser won't get (or see) the html from the second page.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800(v=vs.90).aspx

If you want to completely turn control over to a second page then you need to use `Response.Redirect`.  If your business rules say you can't use this, then I'd suggest you revisit the business rules and change them.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing much of the code, it's hard to really debug this issue. Use the Response.Redirect function instead.

```
Response.Redirect("~/Success.aspx");
```

Comment: its a suggestion, but not an answer to the question.

Comment: The OP didn't ask a question. He also did not mention that Response.Redirect could not be used due to a business rule (I'm not sure what sort of business rule that would be). Response.Redirect typically handles what he was requesting. dotctor also had a similar answer given the limited information provided in the initial post.